# Classpath resource not found

Tags: java, dynamic-linking

Right, this one is really strange. I'm trying to build a Java project, which loads stuff at run-time from a `lib.so` file. The file is in the right directory, the classpath is set, but I still get the same error that the file is not found. I `println()`'d the **entire path of the expected file**, which matched **exactly** the absolute physical location and name of that `.so` file.

Basically, it complains **explicitly** that the file cannot be found when **it is there** (the nature of the error explicitly refers to the inability to **find** the file, and not the loading or the functionality or the ELFness of the file).

Any hints?

Comment: problem with absolute/relative path, having a different working directory than you expect maybe?

Comment: That's what I thought, and then I printed out the entire absolute path, which showed that it was looking for the file exactly where I put it.

Comment: Hint: show us the code that loads the file.  Show us the error message.  Boil down your code until all it does is load this library and do one simple operation with it, and show us ALL of that.  So far what you've done is tell us that everything is right but it doesn't work.  Java error messages are great in general, but you've stepped into the world of non-java code, and I wouldn't put this much faith into the exact wording of the message.  Meanwhile, you've not given us much real information.

Comment: Fair enough. Basically I'm using JNI to load a c++ compiled `.so` library. I'm using `System.load()` as is common in JNI. I'm catching the associated `exception`s and the one that is being thrown is "resource not found". I cannot "boil down the code" as it is a huge project. This is where the problem is, and this is what is being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem was solved after explicitly querying the java classpath at run-time using

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

and printing out all the results. It showed that the *path of the expected file* was relative to a different *classpath* which in turn was relative to the *current directory* of the project.